# Is Network Manager widget supposed to be installed by default in KDE? Even so I don't have it installed and errors prevent from installation

Tags: installation, network-manager, kde

I've looked on the internet but I haven't seen anything that really IMO helps me to try to solve this problem.

Actually the problem that led me to want to install "Network-Manager-KDE" is the fact that I do not have any type of network notification type widget(something that shows what networks are available, if I'm connected or not ect... nn my panel) like most distributions or OS's have on my installation of KDE (at least for now I assume).

So obviously a question I have is:

- Is the "Network-Manager-KDE" something that can be put on a panel and even with errors(see below)? How can I install it?

I have a copy of the output (with the problem) when I try to install it from the Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-kde    
[sudo] password for _____:  

Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree           
Reading state information... Done    
Package network-manager-kde is not available, but is referred to by another package.    
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or    
is only available from another source    
E: Package 'network-manager-kde' has no installation candidate
```

This is pretty much where I am stuck at. If anyone has any information that can help me fix this problem, the help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Did you find it? I think it's called `plasma-widgets-networkmanagement` or `plasma-nm` in 13.10.

Comment: Ficou assim no meu `sudo apt install plasma-nm network-manager-fortisslvpn network-manager-iodine network-manager-l2tp network-manager-openconnect network-manager-ssh network-manager-strongswan network-manager-vpnc libopenconnect5 libpskc0 libstoken1 libtomcrypt1 libtss2-tctildr0 libxmlsec1-openssl fping  ipcalc network-manager-iodine-gnome libstrongswan-extra-plugins libcharon-extra-plugins dnsmasq`